# Configuring Google test project for DLL library

Tags: c++, teamcity, googletest

I have DLL plug-in, which I'd like to test and launch on TeamCity: it contains .h and .cpp files
What is the right strategy to test this DLL:

1. Create a new Test Project in the same solution, configure 'include directory' to see sources and copy DLL project files to Test console project. In this case I have the same solution but in console mode, which I can test in normal way. But if my DLL project will change I need to synchronize source files.
2. Create export function in my DLL, like 'runTests()' which will produce XML file with results. TeamCity will process this? And how should it run this? And some stuff function appears in release DLL...

Answer (score 2):

To unit test our libraries, we create standalone unit testing console executables. so:

1. For each library , we create a  console executable testing each method in the API.
2. Each source file is obviously added to a SCM so modifying files will automatically be reflected into the unit testing program;
3. All this (source updates, compilation, unit testing and doc generation) is added to our CI server (Jenkins) so that all libraries, for all unit testing programs are always recompiled from scratch;
4. The documentation for the library API is constructed with Doxygen using snippet from this program. This has a nice side-effect: changing the API will break your unit tests. So you have to fix your unit tests so your documentation is always up to date.

Comment: I understand about SCM, that both DLL and TEest console are use the same source files, and Test project uses just links. But what if i'll add a _new_ source file to DLL? THen i need to add the link for this file to Test project.

Comment: And if i have .lib for my DLL with all implementations, and just include header files in tests +link that .lib i can recompile test project even after adding files to DLL

Comment: If you need to add a new class to your library (DLL or LIB), then you will most probably add new unit tests in your EXE. As I said, if you recompile ALL needed libraries + your EXE, you are fine. Each time you add a new function in your library's interface, you add at least one unit test in your EXE program.

Comment: Yes. But also i need to add new feature source files link to EXE program +test file. From where original implementation will come: from .cpp linked woth EXE or with .lib linked with EXE?

Comment: I am sorry, i don't get what you mean. You update your local cpp files for LIB and EXE. You recompile your LIB. And you link it with your EXE.

Comment: i'm not sure how to do that. i have dynamic linkage DLL. it doesn't have .lib and it should be loaded dynamically by some host application. in case with static linkage i can link .lib with my Test project and just use headers in tests. But for dynamic linkage library how can i automatically link with DLL?

Comment: Well, this is really not in the scope of this question. I suggest to open a new question for that specific problem to avoid mixing problems/solutions. But from a client point of view (so your TEST EXE), this not really different between linking to a LIB and DLL. However, as it is a plugin, it also depends for what software. When developing our plugins, we try to separate works: functionality in a library (LIB or DLL), and the plugin is only use for the interface between this library and the software it is integrated to.

Comment: i have a code base and it doesn't matter what is the Host Application. I have a set of LOC, i need to cover with integration tests. Thant's all. For E2E testing i'll use Host. And so i have a dynamic DLL with some source code, i need to test. i have 2 variants: 1. to link all source files in my Test project, or to link dll binary (make static linkage).